# Trouble with streams in Scheme

Tags: stream, scheme, racket, lazy-sequences

I'm trying to write a stream that takes as arguments an infinite stream `S`, and two integers `m` and `n`, and returns the stream whose elements are elements of `S` that are multiples of either `m` or `n`.

Unfortunately, my stream only works until I find the first multiple, then it won't progress past that. I'm calling the `cdr` when invoking the stream, so I'm not sure why I'm not looking at the next element.

```
(define stream-car car)
(define (stream-cdr s)
  ((cadr s)))

(define (divisible? n x)
  (zero? (remainder n x)))
(define (stream-cons x s)
  (list x (lambda () s)))

;should loop to find the next multiple in the parameter stream
(define (findnext s m n)
  (if (or (divisible? (stream-car s) m) 
          (divisible? (stream-car s) n))
      (stream-car s)
      (findnext (stream-cdr s) m n)))

;this is my stream
(define (multiples s m n)
  (let ((h (findnext s m n))) 
        ;first need to make sure h is a multiple of 
        ;either m or n, THEN create the list
    (list h
          (lambda ()
            (multiples (stream-cdr s) m n)))))

;below is for testing 
(define (even-nums-from n)
  (list n
        (lambda ()
          (even-nums-from (+ 2 n)))))

(define even-integers
  (even-nums-from 0))

;test cases
(multiples even-integers 4 6);should be a stream with car = 0
(stream-car (multiples even-integers 4 6));should be 0
(stream-cdr (multiples even-integers 4 6));should be a stream with car = 4
(stream-car (stream-cdr (multiples even-integers 4 6))) ;should be 4
(stream-cdr (stream-cdr (multiples even-integers 4 6))) ;should be a stream 
                ;starting with 6-not moving past when we find a multiple
(stream-car (stream-cdr (stream-cdr (multiples even-integers 4 6))))
                ;should be 6
```

My output for the above tests is:

```
(list 0 (lambda () ...))
0
(list 4 (lambda () ...))
4
(list 4 (lambda () ...))
4
```

I'm using DrRacket (advanced student language) and just not sure why my stream is stuck on that first multiple (4). I'm calling stream-cdr when I invoke multiples again, so I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, the problem was I was not updating the passed stream as I found the next multiple. Below is the corrected code (where I now pass a stream with the multiple in the car that will be used in my `multiples` function):

```
;returns the stream with car a multiple of either m or n
(define (findnext s m n)
  (cond ((divisible? (stream-car s) m) s)
        ((divisible? (stream-car s) n) s)      
        (else (findnext (stream-cdr s) m n))))

(define (multiples s m n)
  (let ((h (findnext s m n))) ;h is now an updated stream 
                              ;with car a multiple of one of m or n
    (list (stream-car h)
          (lambda ()
            (multiples (stream-cdr h) m n)))))
```